# Check whether a certain boolean value has appeared continuoulsy

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, series

I have a boolean series as such:

[image]

Here, how do I check whether 'True' value has **at-least** appeared 3 times **in continuation** ?

Which means, in the above series, at indices 0-3, true value has appeared 4 times in continuation !

Can somebody please let me how do we go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Break the question:- You need to count if you get true three times else reset the count and keep traversing the whole array doing this. Lemme know if there is any doubt or if I did anything wrong xD

```
#assuming x to be your series or list
def true3checker(x):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]==True:
            count+=1
            if count==3:
                return True
        else:
            count=0
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks @RitikAttri for your feedback. I tried to apply the codes on following dataset :  
    My_data = pd.Series(np.array(['False','True','True','True','True','False','False']))         However, the result is not as expected. Could you plz let me know where are the codes going wrong. Meanwhile I shall also give it a thought.

Comment: What is the result you are looking for? You want the index where True is in list atleast three times or what are you expecting as a result?

Comment: At-least once in the entire series. I need to know whether 'True' has occurred 3 times in continuation,

Comment: I think I see your problem your data is for some reason I cant think an array inside a series. Just send the the first element of that series which is the array to the function to get the result you are hoping. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following codes work well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#My_data = pd.Series(np.array(['True','True','True','True','False','True','False','True']))
My_data = pd.Series(np.array(['False','True','False','True','False','True','False','True']))
print(My_data)


def TrueValueCheck(Data):
    
    ## size of the series
    Data_size = len(Data) 
    
    ## Define empty array
    Array_Data =  np.empty((0,Data_size ))
    
    ## At-least once in the entire series; 'True' has occurred 3 times in continuation,
    Number_of_times_for_which_True_occurs_continuously = 3
    
    
    for ii in range(Data_size - (Number_of_times_for_which_True_occurs_continuously-1)): 
        
        # checking the successive indices
        if Data[ii] == Data[ii + 1] and Data[ii + 1] == Data[ii + 2]: 

            # Note the value which can be either True or False
            Condition_found_Data = Data[ii]
                        

            # Append if the value is 'True'
            if Condition_found_Data == 'True':
                Array_Data = np.append(Array_Data,Condition_found_Data)
                
                # If at-least once in the entire series; 'True' has occurred 3 times in continuation, then exit
                if len(Array_Data) == 1:
                    break

        
    if len(Array_Data) == 1:
        print("\n","At-least once in the entire series; 'True' has occurred 3 times in continuation.")

    else:
        print("\n","Not even once in the entire series; 'True' could occur 3 times in continuation.") 
        
        
        
TrueValueCheck(My_data)
```